# Angular field initialization vs constructor initialization?

Tags: javascript, angular, constructor, lifecycle

Do fields need to be initialized using the constructor for angular components?  A lot of angular tutorials do:

```
counter: number;

constructor() {
    this.counter = 1;
}
```

Instead of just `counter: number = 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct programming wise,

**Initialized within the constructor**

> It would be good practice to initialized within the constructor , it's kind of code separation of declaration + initialization .
>
> That will increase your code readability and you will be sure that all
>   values initialized within the constructor only. and because in the constructor is when the object is created, and it is when the variable should initialized.

---

**Initialized outside the constructor**

> One issue with initialized using the constructor is , more code to
>   write , when you have alot variable to work with , in that case you
>   should use direct `counter: number = 1` , In this case you can check
>   declaration + initialization in single line , but in above case you
>   have to go through 2 steps declaration + initialization

**It really matters when you choose initialisation within one of the life cycle hook (E.g. `NgOnInit` / `NgAfterViewInit`) vs the `constructor`. Either it's just a coding style**