# Multiple possible variable assignment in angular

Tags: angular, variable-assignment, angular-services

I need clarification of on variable assignment in an Angular service,

I am new to Angular and I wish to have a deep understanding of the implications if any of assigning a variable in these three locations as illustrated bellow.

**Case 1**

```
    import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FavoriteMovieService implements OnInit {

      sampleArray;    

      constructor() {
        this.sampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      }

      ngOnInit() { }
    }
```

**Case 2**

```
    import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FavoriteMovieService implements OnInit {

      sampleArray;    

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.sampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      }
    }
```

**Case 3**

```
    import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FavoriteMovieService implements OnInit {

      sampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];;    

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

**Version information**

```
  Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7
```

Comment: Do you have a specific *question*? What do you mean *"inconsistent"*, for example; did you expect these three different options to have the same behaviour and, if so, why?

Comment: I just need to know the implications if any.

Comment: Have you tried them out? What *problem* are you trying to solve? Most of this isn't specific to Angular at all, read up on JS classes in general.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, am just been curious if there exist any known implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the differences, please note that the `ngOnInit` won't work at all in your case. It won't get called.

The only lifecycle hook that will work with the services is the `ngOnDestroy`, which will be called when the service got destroyed. All other lifecycle hooks like the `ngOnInit` won't get called as they will only get called for the components and directives.

I will add the differences and include the `ngOnInit` if it is implemented inside a component / directive instead.

For the differences between the constructor assignments and inline direct assignments, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860098/5613720):

> Both are correct programming wise,
>
> **Initialized within the constructor**
>
> > It would be good practice to initialized within the constructor , it's kind of code separation of declaration + initialization .
> >
> > That will increase your code readability and you will be sure that all
> >     values initialized within the constructor only. and because in the constructor is when the object is created, and it is when the variable
> >     should initialized.
>
> ---
>
> **Initialized outside the constructor**
>
> > One issue with initialized using the constructor is , more code to
> >     write , when you have alot variable to work with , in that case you
> >     should use direct `counter: number = 1` , In this case you can check
> >     declaration + initialization in single line , but in above case you
> >     have to go through 2 steps declaration + initialization
>
> **It really matters when you choose initialisation within one of the life cycle hook (E.g. `NgOnInit` / `NgAfterViewInit`) vs the
>   `constructor`. Either it's just a coding style**

For the constructor and ngOnInit hook, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/5613720):

> The `Constructor` is a default method of the class that is executed
>   when the class is instantiated and ensures proper initialization of
>   fields in the class and its subclasses. Angular or better Dependency
>   Injector (DI) analyzes the constructor parameters and when it creates
>   a new instance by calling `new MyClass()` it tries to find providers
>   that match the types of the constructor parameters, resolves them and
>   passes them to the constructor like
>
> ```
> new MyClass(someArg);
> ```
>
> `ngOnInit` is a life cycle hook called by Angular2 to indicate that
>   Angular is done creating the component.
>
> We have to import `OnInit` in order to use like this (actually
>   implementing `OnInit` is not mandatory but considered good practice):
>
> ```
> import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
> ```
>
> then to use the method of `OnInit` we have to implement in the class
>   like this.
>
> ```
> export class App implements OnInit{
>   constructor(){
>      //called first time before the ngOnInit()
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit(){
>      //called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> > Implement this interface to execute custom initialization logic after your directive's data-bound properties have been initialized.
> >     ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, 
> >     and before any of its children have been checked. 
> >     It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.
>
> Mostly we use `ngOnInit` for all the initialization/declaration and
>   avoid stuff to work in the constructor. The constructor should only be
>   used to initialize class members but shouldn't do actual "work".
>
> So you should use `constructor()` to setup Dependency Injection and
>   not much else. ngOnInit() is better place to "start" - it's where/when
>   components' bindings are resolved.
>
> For more information refer here:
>
> - https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846307/5043867

Comment: Sure np. Can you please Accept the answer if it answered your questions? Thanks!